# Equality, tuples and sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, terminology, definition

Let $A$ be a set and $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose we have an $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and an $m$-tuple $(b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ of elements of $A$. Without assuming anything about the relation between $n$ and $m$, does the equality
$$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(b_1,\ldots,b_m)$$
imply $n=m$? What happens if $n\ne m$? Surely that would not give a contradiction since $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\ne(b_1,\ldots,b_m)$ would be just as ridiculous for $n\ne m$.

This problem doesn't occur with finite sequences: i.e. with members of $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A^{[1,n]}$. If $x,y\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A^{[1,n]}$ and $x=y$, then domain of $x$ must be equal to the domain of $y$, since we are dealing with an equality of functions. For example, if $x:[1,n]\rightarrow A$ and $y:[1,m]\rightarrow A$ and $x=y$, then by definition $n=m$. Is it the same case for tuples?

Comment: It depends on how you define these $k$-tuples. In any sensible way of defining them you should get $(a_1,...,a_n) = (b_1,...,b_m) \implies m=n$. E.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_nested_sets).

Comment: The wikipedia article defines equality only for the case $n=m$: i.e. it defines equality for $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\ldots, b_n)$. I can't see how the construction of tuples forces $m=n$ for arbitrary $n,m$.

Comment: If $n\ne m$, $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle\ne\langle b_1,\ldots,b_m\rangle$ is not only not ridiculous: it’s true for any reasonable definition of tuples.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Do you mean $n\ne m$ allows us to assert $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\ne(b_1,\ldots,b_m)$? How can it? If $n\ne m$, how could we even compare the tuples?

Comment: @NCS: Because with any reasonable definition of $n$-tuple it can be proved.

Comment: Yes I would like to be able to prove it! Can you please help me? Which construction of tuples would you recommend?

Comment: @NCS: For this purpose the easiest would probably be the definition of tuples as functions (as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Definitions), for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "this problem doesn't occur with finite sequences", but $n$-tuples ARE finite sequences. Very commonly, they are defined as such. Even if they are given some different set-theoretic construction, the $n$-tuple with entries $a_i$ for $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ can be identified with the function $i \mapsto a_i$.

(As far as I've been taught, every indexed set is a function; $n_i$ is just an alternative notation for $n(i)$.)

Of course, if $n \neq m$, then any $n$-tuple $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$ is not equal to any $m$-tuple $(b_1, \dotsc, b_m)$. This should be included in any definition of equality of tuples.

If $n = m$, then the tuples are equal if $a_i = b_i$ for each $i \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that tuples as finite sequences is just some possible definition. There are other set-theoretic definitions where equality is just set equality. Of course the desired property still holds in this case.

Comment: @KeeferRowan: I added some comments on that. (When defining them as finite sequences, equality is still just set equality, no?)